# VIM custom function definition / location

Tags: vim

I have problem with basic VIM function:(I tried googling and cannot find the answer)

1. How can I list all custom
   function.(I did :function and cannot
   find my custom function)
2. How can I get the definition of the
   function in the custom function list
   (or where they are stored).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose your function is called MyFunction, then the following works for me:

```
:verbose function My<tab>
```

(for <tab> I mean actually press tab)

if your function is loaded in vim it should show up there and you can see where it was defined.

Comment: Thanks, now I can do (:verbose function to list all function and their location. :verbose function partOfName<tab>, and :verbose function functionName)

Comment: @kite `verbose function` will not list *all* functions, only those that are not anonymous. For example, some of my plugins does not contain non-anonymous functions at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find your custom function in output of `function` without arguments, then it is probably an anonymous function declared like that:

```
let g:dict={}
function g:dict.f()
    echo "here"
endfunction
```

In this case the only way to get its definition is to use `function g:dict.f` (prepend `verbose` as @skeept suggested to know where it is defined). Note that you cannot use tab completion here and you cannot get a list of all anonymous functions.

Instead of `g:dict.f` in `function g:dict.f` you can use `function {N}`, where `N` is any expression that returns anonymous function number, for example `function {substitute(string(g:dict.f), '^.*\(\d\+\).*$', '\1', '')}`. Or just `function {242}` if all you get is a error like that: `Error detected while processing function 243..242:` and want to see the definition of function 242.

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous function method